# Remove repeating consecutive elements from array

Tags: arrays, matlab

I need some help with arrays in MATLAB:
Imagine have an array like this

```
a = [1,1,1,1,2,2,4,4,4,7,7,7,1,1,1,1]
```

to and like to get this array:

```
b = [1,2,4,7,1]
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just index your array with its [**`diff`**](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html)erences:

```
b = a( [true  logical( diff(a(:)).') ] )
```

---

```
b =

     1     2     4     7     1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1,1,1,1,2,2,4,4,4,7,7,7,1,1,1,1];
b = [];
length = size(a);
i = 1;
while i<=length 
    if(a(1,i) ~= a(1,i-1))
        b(1,i) = a(1,i);
    end
    i = i+1;
end
disp(b);
```

hope it will help.

Comment: Error: Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.