# Pad consecutive repeating elements with zeros

Tags: matlab, vector

Consider the following vector:

```
A=[1 1 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 3 2 2 4 4 4 4]
```

How can any consecutive values can be padded such that the result vector will be given by:

```
B=[1 0 0 2 0 0 1 0 0 0 3 2 0 4 0 0 0]
```

Consider cases where the first element is non-zero.

Comment: I'd like to suggest you to take the [tour] and read [ask] anew, as you seem to be lacking one of the most important parts of Stack Overflow in your latest questions: **effort**. You might have tried coding something yourself, read up on documentation etc, but it's not showing. Please do put effort into solving your own questions before asking here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40819571/7328782), which removes consecutive repeating elements, we can build an answer to this question.

```matlab
A = [ 1 1 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 3 2 2 4 4 4 4];
I = [false,diff(A)==0];
B = A; B(I) = 0;
```